# Magento Abandoned cart email is not a default feature?

Tags: magento2, email, abandoned-cart

I want to confirm that the Magento 2 Abandoned cart email is not a default feature? MagePlaza extension inside the Magento seems need to get paid for this function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is

You can enable that feature in Store>Configuration>Engagement Cloud>Abandoned Carts

but the only issue is, it is also a paid service.

reference: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/configuration/engagement-cloud/abandoned-carts.html